# Can we disable all salable quantity modules in mganeto2.4.1

Tags: inventory, magento2.4.1, salable, reservations

We manage our stock in another system and update the quantity field as orders come in. This is causing issues as suddenly the salable quantities are lowering, and never reset.

Is there a way to reset this salable quantity? Is there a way to disable all Salable modules?

Ex. I add a new product and: qty=1 salableqty=1

Now I sold product and salableqty=0 but qty still = 1

The product was still visible on the front end but was impossible to add to the cart.

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable salable quantity since it's hardcoded on Magento, although you can create a module to disable it or use one.

For example installing [AmpersandHQ/magento2-disable-stock-reservation](https://github.com/AmpersandHQ/magento2-disable-stock-reservation) that allows you to decrement only the product' qty on order placement.

After the install you need to clear the stock reservation table 'inventory_reservation' to reset the values. I recommend doing that only if you don't have real orders yet.